# problems with navbar wrapper. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, css-float, navbar

Almost everything is floating left, but I will like the navigation menu floating right and the logo floating left, both in the same centered div (with margin auto when the max width of 1170px is reached)
[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/xellos81/pen/cveCw)

```
  .static-navbar-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.09);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<style>
    .wrapper {width:1170px;margin:0px auto;}
    #nav-menu {float:right;}
    #logo{float:left;}
    .clear_fix {clear:both;}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="nav-menu">
            Navigation Menu
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
            Logo Image
    </div>

    <div class="clear_fix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work.
Have you tried my CodePen link?